# Golang Gorm Fiber / argon2.Config undefined

Tags: go, go-gorm, go-templates, go-fiber

I'm trying to switch from PHP to GO, but I'm stuck at one point, I ask for your help.

I'm trying to create a password hashing function using Argon2, but I keep getting the error "undefined: argon2.Config" when I use "argon2.Config{}". I've recompiled the project multiple times, but I can't seem to find a solution. I'm requesting your assistance with this issue.

```
func hashPassword(password string) []byte {
    // Şifreleme parametreleri
    timeCost := 1                 // İşlem süresi
    memory := 64 * 1024           // // Bellek miktarı
    threads := 4                  //  İş parçacığı sayısı
    keyLength := 32               // Oluşturulacak hash uzunluğu
    salt := []byte("unique_salt") // Her kullanıcı için benzersiz

    // Argon2 işlemi için hasher oluştur
    hasher := argon2.Config{
        Time:    uint32(timeCost),
        Memory:  uint32(memory),
        Threads: uint8(threads),
        KeyLen:  uint32(keyLength),
    }

    // Şifreyi hashle
    hashedPassword := hasher.Hash(password, salt, nil)

    return hashedPassword
}
```

[image: undefined: argon2.Config]

Comment: Could be related to the package version, could you share how you are importing argon and the package version?

Comment: I'm writing code in VSCode, and it automatically installs the package for me. I defined the package version manually in the go.mod file, but it still didn't work. I tried the argon2.IDKey type mentioned below, and it worked. Thanks for your help with the debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using the package `"golang.org/x/crypto/argon2"` you can use `argon2.IDKey()` method. Here is a working example:

```
func HashPassword(password string) (hashedPassword string) {

    const (
        timeCost  uint32 = 1         // İşlem süresi
        memory    uint32 = 64 * 1024 // // Bellek miktarı
        threads   uint8  = 4         //  İş parçacığı sayısı
        keyLength uint32 = 32        // Oluşturulacak hash uzunluğu
    )

    salt := []byte("unique_salt") // Her kullanıcı için benzersiz

    // generate hashedpassword
    hash := argon2.IDKey([]byte(password), salt, timeCost, memory, threads, keyLength)

    // Base64 encode the salt and hashed password.
    b64Salt := base64.RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString(salt)
    b64Hash := base64.RawStdEncoding.EncodeToString(hash)

    format := "$argon2id$v=%d$models=%d,t=%d,p=%d$%s$%s"

    // final password in recommended format
    hashedPassword = fmt.Sprintf(format, argon2.Version, memory, timeCost, threads, b64Salt, b64Hash)
    return hashedPassword
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support. My problem has been resolved.